# Spring boot rest external tomcat 401 error

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have spring boot REST application that works perfectly fine when running on embedded tomcat. But as soon as I deploy it on external tomcat it gives 401 even for login requests

I followed https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/ and was able to deploy on tomcat.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder         application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private EntryPointUnauthorizedHandler unauthorizedHandler;

  @Autowired
  private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private SecurityService securityService;

  @Autowired
  public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder
      .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws     Exception {
    AuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new     AuthenticationTokenFilter();
        authenticationTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
return authenticationTokenFilter;
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityService securityService() {
    return this.securityService;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
      .csrf()
        .disable()
      .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(this.unauthorizedHandler)
        .and()
      .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
      .cors();

    // Custom JWT based authentication
    httpSecurity
      .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(),     UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
```

}

Response on login

```
{
"timestamp": 1522175007525,
"status": 401,
"error": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Access Denied",
"path": "/test-app/api/auth"
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by changing the context path.

In application.properties file I have set

```
server.contextPath=/api
```

But it was totally ignored by tomcat and the final path changed from app/api/service to app/service

Rest all is working fine